# Trying to boot from install cd gives error

Tags: 13.10

I'm trying to install linux 13.10 desktop onto my old sony vaio vgn-s580p.

I've also tried 12.4.3.

Both have given me the same error which references nouveau_perf_init.

I've read that this has to do with conflicts with a nvidia graphics card. I have the GeForce go 6400.

However i can't find anywhere what to actually do to fix the problem. I have a screenshot of the error but I don't see a way to post it here.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to log in to a console session if you press alt+ctrl+f1?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad No, the system seems to be completely frozen. I am attempting to boot from a CD as my BIOS has no option for USB boot.

Comment: You could try to boot in resque mode and install drivers for your VGA. It looks to me that this might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As I take a look at the specs of your computer (http://www.cnet.com/laptops/sony-vaio-vgn-s580/4505-3121_7-31516554.html), it seems to be too small to run Ubuntu properly.

If you want to give a new life to this machine, you may want to try lubuntu or lxle.

http://lubuntu.net/

http://lxle.net/

Make sure you use the 32 bits version, there are chances that your processor doesn't support 64 bits.